# Does the order/direction of fsync matter?

Tags: c++, fsync

Let's say I write out some files and directories to a usb thumb drive.

```
/media/drive1/newFolder1/
/media/drive1/newFolder1/newfile1
/media/drive1/newFolder1/newfile2
```

I've created a folder, `newFolder1` and two files `newfile1` and `newfile2`.

Syncing does not happen automatically, so I'd need to `fsync` the changes.

So I need to call `fsync` on `newFolder1`, `newfile1` and `newfile2`.

Question is, does it matter the order in which I do this?

Comment: What about it might matter to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't matter for content, but last-modified-times could be wrong if the directory is not synced after the files.